# C++ Object Pool implementation throwing SIGILL error

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I'm trying to learn a bit about memory in C++, and so I'm working on a simple bare-bones Object Pool implementation. Here is what I have so far:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
class MemoryPool {
public:
    MemoryPool() = default;

    template<typename... Args>
    T* create(Args&&... args) {
        auto idx = 0;
        while (isOccupied[idx]) ++idx;

        if (idx >= Size) throw std::out_of_range("No memory left");
        isOccupied[idx] = true;

        auto t = data[idx];

        auto datum = T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        data[idx] = datum; // error here
    }

    void destroy(T* element) {
        auto idx = 0;
        while (&data[idx] != element) idx++;
        isOccupied[idx] = false;

        operator delete(element);
    }

private:
    T* data = reinterpret_cast<T*>(std::malloc(sizeof(T) * Size));
    std::array<bool, Size> isOccupied{};
};
```

However, when I'm debugging the implementation, I get a SIGILL error when attempting to assign to `data[idx]`. I'm not sure why this is, since I'm fairly certain I properly initialized `data` and `datum`.

Minimum reproduceable example:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    explicit A(int i) : i(i) {}
};

int main() {
    MemoryPool<A, 3> pool{};
    auto a = pool.create(1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using C++20 and Clang 10 with the CLion IDE.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your `create` function fails to return a value when it is supposed to return a `T*`.  Undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One error is that your `create` function fails to return a value when it should return a `T*`.  Thus undefined behavior is invoked.

```
template<typename... Args>
T* create(Args&&... args)
{
  //...
}  // gets to here without returning a value
```

Since undefined behavior has been invoked, there is no longer any reasoning as to what the program will do.